# c:forEach loop printing square bracket delimiters

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am passing an attribute named dataTable into my JSP that is a list of lists of strings.  In the JSP if I output the attribute, using ${dataTable} it prints it out in raw format:

```
[[Header1, Header2, Header3], [A, B, C], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I can print an item directly like this:

```
${dataTable[1][2]}
```

which outputs: C

Then when I wrote a nested c:forEach loop to print the table, the square brackets at the end of each row are included, but not the square brackets on the entire object.

My code for that is:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${dataTable}">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${row} ">
        <span>${item}</span>
    </c:forEach>
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

Which results in:

```
        <span>[Header1</span>
        <span> Header2</span>
        <span> Header3] </span>
    <br />
        <span>[A</span>
        <span> B</span>
        <span> C] </span>
    <br />
        <span>[1</span>
        <span> 2</span>
        <span> 3] </span>
    <br />
```

That is almost what I am going for, I just do not want the square brackets at the beginning and end of every row.

What am I missing which is causing those square brackets to show up when iterating through, but not when I access an item directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the exact code from your page?

Comment: Yes, I am just using a simple generic table until I get it working right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra space after `${row}` that's causing the list to get "toStringed" on this line `<c:forEach var="item" items="${row} ">`, change it to `<c:forEach var="item" items="${row}">` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Indeed, also note that the extra space has ended up after the `]` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You said that `dataTable` is a list of strings - that means that the inner `forEach` tag is iterating over a string. In the Apache JSTL implementation (1.2 source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForEachSupport.java#ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator%28java.lang.String%29)), iterating over a string parses it into comma-separated tokens. So the string `"[A, B, C]"` gets parsed into the list `["[A", " B", " C]"'`.

To get your desired behavior, try defining `dataTable` using nested lists, e.g. `[["A", "B", "C"], ["1", "2", "3"]]` instead of `["[A, B, C]", "[1, 2, 3]"]`.

Comment: dataTable is a list of lists of strings, before it was put into the attribute it was initialized as  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>